# Pass additional variables to sentry using raven-js

Tags: javascript, sentry, raven

I'm trying to catch a js error using raven-js. I have following code

```
...
try
  rs.endsWith "#{rsp.source_identifier}/"
catch e
  Raven.captureException(e, {extra:{rs: rs, app: app}})
```

I see this error in sentry, but i dont see extra variables, e.g. rs and app . Only extra that i see is:

"session:duration": 581889

in full error json i see following:

```
  "errors": [
    {
      "type": "invalid_attribute",
      "name": "rs"
    },
    {
      "type": "invalid_attribute",
      "name": "app"
    }
  ],
  "extra": {
    "session:duration": 581889
  },
```

How to pass this vars to sentry, so they actually appear in sentry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should show up under the "Additional data" box if you scroll down to the bottom of the issue view.

If this isn't working for you, can you reach out to me? I'm eric@getsentry.com.

Comment: All works now. The problem was that previously i send it without extra tag, than changed it to use extra tag, and in sentry new entries was showing in source code like they are using extra tag, although the real requests was made using cached version without extra